# GCC recommendations and options for fastest code

Tags: c++, unix, gcc

I'm distributing a C++ program with a makefile for the Unix version, and I'm wondering what compiler options I should use to get the fastest possible code (it falls into the category of programs that can use all the computing power they can get and still come back for more), given that I don't know in advance what hardware, operating system or gcc version the user will have, and I want above all else to make sure it at least works correctly on every major Unix-like operating system.

Thus far, I have `g++ -O3 -Wno-write-strings`, are there any other options I should add? On Windows, the Microsoft compiler has options for things like fast calling convention and link time code generation that are worth using, are there any equivalents on gcc?

(I'm assuming it will default to 64-bit on a 64-bit platform, please correct me if that's not the case.)

Comment: Be aware that fastcall isn't *always* faster. As always when it comes to performance, measure, measure, measure. It's only faster if you've got a benchmark showing that it is.

Comment: It's difficult to know what optimizations might fasten the execution of your program when we don't know what it does. And even if we knew, there is so many differents configurations around the world that it is unlikely to find an option that works faster on almost all those configurations.

Comment: Depending on what your program does, you might be able to deactivate RTTI. It should get you some speed up, but forbid the use of a number of features.

Comment: Theorem prover. (All integer calculations, pointers and branches, but the answers discussing floating point might be useful for other people.) Of course it's always difficult to be sure, but at the end of the day one has to make a decision without having seen the user's machine. I tried disabling RTTI, but it didn't seem to make any difference in the generated code.

Comment: Now i know this might be a little off-topic, but i will try anyway: experimenting with compiler options might help you a lot, but if your code (algorithms) are slow, then no clever optimization will help you. Profile your code, find bottlenecks and fix them. I'm not saying that your code is bad, this is just a friendly suggestion!

Comment: PeterK - good heavens, yes. I've already implemented some optimizations worth more than 10 orders of magnitude speedup on typical problems (estimate, hard to test for obvious reasons) and there's a lot more to go. If accused of being therefore irrational for spending any time fiddling with compiler settings, I will plead _nolo contendere_ :-)

Comment: Over 10 orders of magnitude? You optimized something that has a runtime of roughly 4 months down to 1 millisecond? Wow.

Comment: Build with LTO (Link Time Optimization) enabled - it slows down your compile but has a general positive effect on the speed of the resulting program.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Without knowing any specifics on your program it's hard to say. O3 covers most of the optimisations.  The remaining options come "at a cost".  If you can tolerate some random rounding and your code isn't dependent on IEEE floating point standards then you can try -Ofast.  This disregards standards compliance and can give you faster code.

The remaining optimisations flags can only improve performance of certain programs, but can even be detrimental to others.  Look at the available flags in the [gcc documentation on optimisation flags](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html) and benchmark them.

Another option is to enable C99 (-std=c99) and inline appropriate functions.  This is a bit of an art, you shouldn't inline everything, but with a little work you can get your code to be faster (albeit at the cost of having a larger executable).

If speed is really an issue I would suggest either going back to Microsoft's compiler, or to try Intel's.  I've come to appreciate how slow some gcc compiled code can be, especially when it involves math.h.

EDIT: Oh wait, you said C++? Then disregard my C99 paragraph, you can inline already :)

Comment: Funny, I've come to appreciate how slow MSVC compiled code can be :-) I also don't think that applies, as the poster seems to want GCC so it can target Spark, PPC, "every major Unix-like operating system".

Comment: Actually I've never used the MSVC compiler.  I'm surprised it's not fast, you would think MS would have optimised the crap out of it seeing that they probably have 90% of their software compiled on it.  I am comparing to Intel's which I have used extensively.  Yeah, I just realised that the OP wants it to target most unixes making it even harder to list a fixed set of opt flags.

Comment: I'm compiling the Windows binary with the Microsoft compiler (about 5 to 10% faster than GCC by my tests), this is for the Unix distribution. As far as I now understand it, -Ofast etc may (or may not) help floating-point code, but for integer code -O3 already gives you the full Monty?

Comment: Ok as far as I know (and the doc seems to agree) Ofast is funsafe-math, which applies only to floating point math, so if you've got only integer math it's probably not going to help.  However, I wouldn't say O3 gives you the full monty, there are other options which O3 doesn't use since they don't guarantee faster code.  Optimisation is highly program and architecture dependent. Its possible that disabling one of the O3 opts could improve your performance.  If performance is that vital benchmark your program on a set of machines and have a set of flags for each architecture in your makefile.

Answer (score 19):

I would try profile guided optimization:

> `-fprofile-generate`   Enable options
>   usually used for instrumenting
>   application to produce profile useful
>   for later recompilation with profile
>   feedback based optimization. You must
>   use `-fprofile-generate` both when
>   compiling and when linking your
>   program.   The following options are
>   enabled: `-fprofile-arcs`,
>   `-fprofile-values`, `-fvpt`.

You should also give the compiler hints about the architecture on which the program will run.
For example if it will only run on a server and you can compile it on the same machine as the server, you can just use `-march=native`.
Otherwise you need to determine which features your users will all have and pass the corresponding parameter to GCC.

(Apparently you're targeting 64-bit, so GCC will probably already include more optimizations than for generic x86.)

Comment: For those who are wondering how exactly to use guided optimization: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4366805

Answer (score 12):

### -OFast

---

Please try **-OFast** instead of **-O3**

Also here is a list of flags you might want to selectively enable.

> -ffloat-store
>
> -fexcess-precision=style
>
> -ffast-math
>
> -fno-rounding-math
>
> -fno-signaling-nans
>
> -fcx-limited-range
>
> -fno-math-errno
>
> -funsafe-math-optimizations
>
> -fassociative-math
>
> -freciprocal-math
>
> -ffinite-math-only
>
> -fno-signed-zeros
>
> -fno-trapping-math
>
> -frounding-math
>
> -fsingle-precision-constant
>
> -fcx-fortran-rules

A complete list of the flags and their detailed description is available **[here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)**

Comment: `-fcx-limited-range` `-freciprocal-math` and `-fassociative-math` are listed twice.

Comment: Thanks @Hydranix. Removed the duplicates from the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Apart from what others have already suggested, try `-flto`. It enables link-time optimization which, in some cases, can do a real magic.

For further information see [LLVM description](https://llvm.org/docs/LinkTimeOptimization.html) and [GCC optimize options](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html)

Answer (score 8):

Consider using `-fomit-frame-pointer` unless you need to debug with gdb (yuck). That will give the compiler one more register to use for variables (otherwise this register is wasted for useless frame pointers).

Also you may use something like `-march=core2` or more generally `-march=native` to enable the compiler to use newer instructions and further tune the code for the specified architecture, but for this you must be sure your code will not be expected to run on older processors.

Comment: I find Visual Studio Code (with the Microsoft C/C++ extension) and GDB work quite nicely together for debugging when on Linux

Comment: As a side note, -O and -O{n} all enable -fomit-frame-pointer without having to call it out :) https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

Comment: You don't need a frame pointer to debug with gdb.

Answer (score 5):

gcc -O3 is not guaranteed to be the fastest. -O2 is often a better starting point. After that, profile guided optimization and trying out specific options: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Optimize-Options.html

It's a long read, but probably worth it.

Note that a "Link Time Code Generation" (MSVC) aka "Link Time Optimization" is available in gcc 4.5+

By the way, there is no specific "fastcall" calling convention for Win64. There is only "the" calling convention: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc300794.aspx

Comment: Concerning your point "By the way, there is no specific "fastcall" calling convention for Win64. There is only "the" calling convention":

There also exists the "vectorcall" call convention under Win64: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/vectorcall?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'fastcall' on x86-64 - both Win64 and Linux ABI define register-based calling ("fastcall") as the only calling convention (though Linux uses more registers).

Comment: Under 64 bit Windows, there also exists the "vectorcall" call convention: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/vectorcall?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=vs-2019